# Two Submit Buttons, Want to Run Separate Parts of a Script Based on Which is Clicked

Tags: javascript

Ok so I have two submit buttons, a standard submit button, as well as a , etc, etc button.

Anyway, the second button is a delete button, but both of them go to the same function, because of onSubmit.

What I want to do is set up an if statement to see if the delete button was pressed.

Here's the code to generate the delete button (the value is generated by PHP):

```
<button type="submit" name="del" id="deletebutton" value="'.$org.'">Delete</button>
```

Here's my idea so far:

```
    if (document.getElementById('deletebutton').value != '') {
     BLAHBLAHBLAH CODE HERE for delete button click;
    }
else {
BLAHBLAHBLAH Code for non-delete button click;
}
```

but my IDE (NetBeans) seems to show an error when I try to do this. How would the correct way to do this be?

EDIT: DOH typo!

Comment: Well what error is it showing ? And why not just look at the browser console instead of netbeans ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (document.getElementById('deletebutton').value != '' {
```

You forgot the closing parenthasis, that is why you are getting an error:

```
if (document.getElementById('deletebutton').value != '') {
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could consider, have both buttons have an onclick action which sets a hidden value in the form. You can then check that in your onsubmit function. Plenty of ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you could create and assign a event handler to each of the form buttons and pass the reference to the function to determine which was fired, like this for example.

```
<script>
  function whichButton(o){
    if(o.id == "deletebutton"){
       alert("delete was pressed");
      //document.yourFormName.submit();
    }else{
     // document.yourFormName.submit();
      alert("delete wasn\'t pressed");
    }

   return false
  }
</script>
```

set up the button

```
 <form name="yourFormName" action="" onsubmit="return false">
    <button type="submit" name="del" id="notdeletebutton" value="'.$org.'" onclick="return whichButton(this)">Not Delete</button>
    <button type="submit" name="del" id="deletebutton" value="'.$org.'" onclick="return whichButton(this)">Delete</button>
  </form>
```