# Element's Value is Null - I am not representing this correctly, I think

Tags: javascript

Here's my code - I am getting an error in my firebug console that document.getElementById('deletebutton').value is null.

EDIT: To explain what I want - I want code to execute if one of two submit buttons is pressed - this is code to determine whether it was the delete button that was pressed (if not, it should have a null value) and it will execute certain code. Whenever I try to use this though, I keep getting the error message "'deletebutton' is null.

Here's the HTML:

```
<button type="submit" name="del" id="deletebutton" value="'.$org.'">Delete</button>
```

How do I account in my program for this? I set it to '', but I believe null would be a better option. Would I do:

```
if (document.getElementById('deletebutton').value != null
```

?

Here's the actual code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

function formValidation() {

var ids = ["orgname", "cultpicklist", "catpicklist", "servpicklist"]
    formValue = 1;

    if (document.getElementById('deletebutton').value != '' && document.getElementById('orgname').value === "") {
      formValue = 0;
    }
else {
for (var i = 0, len = ids.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById(ids[i]).value === "") {
       formValue = 0;
       break;
    }
}
}

 if (formValue == 1) {
           return true;
      } else if (formValue == 0) {
           alert('Please fill out all required fields');
           return false;
      }
}
//]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Is `document.getElementById('deletebutton').value is null.` the *acutal* error? Or is it more like `TypeError: can not read property "value" of null`?

Comment: document.getElementById("deletebutton") is null

Comment: @AndrewAlexander: Everything you've provided in your question indicates that your code should work. This means that you've excluded from the question the part that is causing it to break. If the code runs on the click of a button, and the element exists when the button is clicked, then you won't get that error. The value `null` is what `getElementById` returns when it doesn't find an element, and you can't access properties on `null`.

Comment: i added a post to your other question check it and see if that helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387476/two-submit-buttons-want-to-run-separate-parts-of-a-script-based-on-which-is-cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite understand your code very well, because the HTML part is missing.
it'd be great if you could provide a jsfiddle or something similar in order to have a more accurate portrait of your situation.

Anyhow, I believe that if you just want to test the existence of the item with id "deletebutton" probably you could try something like

```
if( document.getElementById('deletebutton') != null )
```